# Angular JS - Remember view input content on view change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a situation that I have simplified into the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/y3g3p4kL/

Html:

```html
<a href="#/">Tab 1</a> |
<a href="#/2">Tab 2</a>
<hr>
<div ng-view></div>
```

Js:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        template: 'Tab 1<br><input-directive></input-directive>'
      }).
      when('2', {
        template: 'Tab 2'
      });
  }]);

myApp.directive('inputDirective', function($http) {
    return {
        restrict:"E",
        template:'<input type="text" ng-model="text">'
    }
});
```

There are a series of tabs which link to different angular urls which are managed using ng-route.

Inside the view for the first tab is a directive that has an input field. The problem I am having is that when you navigate to tab 2, the input within the directive for tab 1 is forgotten (because $scope.$destroy() is called for the directive when the view changes).

What is the best approach to prevent this from happening, so that when you navigate back to tab 1, any text you have inputted is remembered?

I'm happy to consider a completely different approach if nessessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some in depth searching I think I've found the solution to this.

I think, once upon a time the solution would have been to cache the model in a singleton service, but fortunately there is a nice plugin available as part of ui-router-extras called sticky states:

http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky